# How to smooth fluctuating DC from transformer?

Tags: transformer, ac-dc, bridge-rectifier

For an audio amplifier, I designed an AC to DC (220v to 12V 2A) power circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6xqiJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I powered my amplifier with the circuit above, it gave a noise which sounded like a 50Hz non-filtered DC noise. That is the reason I am having to power my amplifier using a 12 Volt battery.

What mistake did I make there in the circuit above resulting in unsmoothed DC output?

Note:
I did not use any bridge rectifier ICs.  I used 4 diodes for rectification.

Comment: The circuit above will produce unsmoothed DC. Since there is no regulation, the voltage will have ripple from discharging and charging of the capacitor. 12V AC will also become about 17V DC when rectified into capacitor, and with no load it can be even higher.

Comment: @Justme: The output will be smoothed by the capacitors - just not enough.

Comment: Is R2 really 100 Ω? To get 2 A through it you would need a 200 V supply.

Comment: @Transistor Fixed the schematic

Comment: So what's the purpose of C2 and R2? You need to supply more information. What kind of amplifier? Schematic of amplifier? If you short the audio input does it still hum?

Comment: An amplifier is supposed to have enough power supply rejection to run on that kind of supply.

Comment: @Transistor The C2 and R2 were supposed to reduce the ripples but didn't work , that amplifier is TDA2050 audio amplifier ic of 32 watts

Comment: @bobflux In my case, that didn't work

Comment: Please give link to amplifier docs

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.unisonic.com.tw/datasheet/TDA2050.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjXr6LiobzvAhVqRzABHXZ_DaMQFjATegQIBhAC&sqi=2&usg=AOvVaw2AV6rr5fVdQnUGF7lQB_j5

Comment: Is the amp using single supply (positive and ground) or split supply (positive, negative and ground)? If it is a split supply, how is the VCC/2 bias generated? Can you show a schematic ?

Comment: R2 will reduce the ripple. But the reduced ripple will be seen across C2, leaving the ripple across C1 unchanged. (And you won't get much power through R2. This is fine for supplying a preamp though)

Comment: @BrianDrummond I suspect a single-supply amplifier where the voltage reference for the input is mid-supply, via a resistor divider. If there is not enough filtering on that, supply ripple goes straight into the output, amplified by the gain of the amp...

Comment: I am using the amplifier in single power  12-0 2A, and schematic is as same as the schematic is given in the data sheet @bobflux

Answer (score 1):

Use a [capacitor multiplier circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance_multiplier).

[Video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wopmEyZKnYo)

[image]

This circuit allows to smooth out ripple from the supply.

Many people may advise to use some sort of LDOs, but LDOs aren't good filters.

Comment: What should be the approx value of R1 and C1 ?

Comment: You can watch the video, it explains it very well, values depends on your needs and is very dependent on your setup. If you are unsure, you can just try different values.

Comment: Ok thanks bro I will tick your answer as soon as I find it helpful ☺️

Answer (score 1):

> *When I powered my amplifier with the circuit above, it gave a noise
> which sounded like a 50Hz non-filtered DC noise.*

If it were bridge rectifier ripple noise, it would sound like 100 Hz.

And, if the noise is heard when there is no audio input, then the current drawn from the bridge rectifier's smoothing capacitor(s) will be very low (circa 20 mA) and that means there will be hardly any ripple at all. The impact of this is that it is unlikely to be ripple on the DC rails causing your noise. But you can test the theory by putting a 10 watt 22 Ω resistor across the 12 volt rail. It should draw an extra 545 mA and, if the ripple is the culprit, the hum in your speaker should increase considerably.

I suggest that you may have audio ground loop issues that is causing the noise.

Comment: You are totally wrong this time, even when I disconnect the bluetooth module from the amplifier board, it still outputs noise

Comment: @SubhaJeetSikdar sorry can you explain what it is that I'm wrong about please?

Comment: The audio ground loop

Comment: @SubhaJeetSikdar how can I be totally wrong when I said "I suggest that you may have..."??? Anyway, did you solve the problem?

Comment: It's not totally fixed but yes, noise is reduced a bit, still working on it